# Can i unown a ticket in RT4 in a script?

Tags: perl

I try to create a script that will change the owner based on which queue it is moved. But unfortunately i always get this error message:

```
You can only reassign tickets that you own or that are unowned
```

I tried to remove the owner first, and set it to nobody but this of course does not work either:

```
condition: on queue change
action: user defined
template: blank
stage: transaction create

____preperation code:
my ($status, $msg) = $self->TicketObj->SetOwner( $RT::Nobody->id ); 
unless( $status ) {
      $RT::Logger->warning( "Preperation: Impossible to assign the ticket to Nobody: $msg" );
return undef;
} 0;

___cleanup code:
my %owners = (
'foo' => 'userbar',
'bla' => 'userfoo',
);


my $QueueName = $self->TicketObj->QueueObj->Name; 
return 1 unless defined($owners{$QueueName}); 

my $MyUser = $owners{$QueueName}; 
$RT::Logger->info("Auto assigning ticket #". $self->TicketObj->id ." to user $MyUser" ); 
my ($status, $msg) = $self->TicketObj->SetOwner( $MyUser ); 
unless( $status ) {
      $RT::Logger->warning( "Impossible to assign the ticket to $MyUser: $msg" );
return undef;
} 1;
```

Is there any possibility to remove the owner of a ticket with a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here: http://lists.bestpractical.com/pipermail/rt-users/2009-September/061521.html

You can force the owner of a ticket by simply using:

```
$ticket->SetOwner(10, 'Force');
```